# How to create a temporarily text box

Tags: javascript

i'm making a website where the background will be a large photo (interior design company) so the picture is very important. That's why i've been trying to make a temporarily text box so that people that come on the homepage will see a temporarily welcome message or such but i don't really know how to start or what language I should use in order to this.

I hope anyone can help me to get started. Or where/what i need to search

Thanks in advance

Comment: A 'text box,' for user input or just a box with a 'welcome to the site' message?

Comment: What does the text box have to do with the picture?

Comment: The text box will be used to welcome users and give them an idea of where they are, and what we do. And the text box should be removable or dissappear after a few seconds so that the picture (the text box will come in front of the photo) will be clearly visible. So more of a short note to guests. But i would like to let it fade in or fly into the screen (kinda animated so i think jquery? ) also when it dissappear will be animated if possible

Answer (score 0):

Simple using the [`alert`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) method.
Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display_alert()
{
alert("Welcome to the site!");
}

display_alert();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Or using jquery's [`hide`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide) method.
Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input value="Welcome to the Site!">
</body>
</html>
```